# Strange behavior when reading xml using OPENXML WITH (schema)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please look at following SQL. Can anyone explain the strange behavior? Thanks for any tip, I've no idea why it works differently. I would like to use domain (user defined) types, but it doesn't work correctly as you can see - decimal numbers are rounded.

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[QTY] FROM decimal(18, 3) NULL
GO

DECLARE @XMLDATA xml=N'<Table><Row Value="42.5" /></Table>';
DECLARE @HDOC INT;

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @HDOC OUTPUT, @XMLDATA;

-- this returns 43
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@HDOC, 'Table/Row') WITH (
    Value QTY
);

-- this returns 42.500
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@HDOC, 'Table/Row') WITH (
    Value DECIMAL(18,3)
);

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @HDOC;
GO
```

Comment: I don't see problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMZYj.png

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Apparently the problem only happens with SQL Server versions <= 2008. Your query runs fine in SQL Server 2012, 2014 and 2016